# All countable chains have an upper bound or maximal elements?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, upper-lower-bounds

I have a question that,

> All countable chains have an upper bound or maximal elements?
>   IF a chain is finite, this statement is true.

But, I'm not sure in the case of when a chain is countably infinite.

So, I would refine my question

> All countably infinite chains have an upper bound or maximal elements?

or

> Does the set of natural numbers has an upper bound or maximal elements in range of natural numbers?

Comment: With the usual order, of course not, because $n \leq n+1$ for any $n$, so there can't be an upper bound to the chain of natural numbers.

Comment: I wonder that this can be a proper example.  In unusual case, for example, **( even number chain ) < (odd number chain )**
and odd number is always bigger than even number.
Then, for even number chain, there always exist upper bounds, it's odd numbers.  
But, in case , there's no maximal in infinite even number chain.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly the natural numbers have no maximal element. Suppose that there is a maximal element $n$, then $n+1 > n$ a contradiction.